# How to call Appwrite function from postman?

Tags: function, http, invoke, appwrite

I have appwrite instance deployed locally. I have created a function and deployed successfully. How can I call that function from postman through HTTP request?

My local instance URL: `http://localhost/v1`

Function path as per `appwrite.json` is `functions/greetings`

I am passing the required projectId and API-KEY.
I am using the below URL to call the function:

```
http://localhost/v1/functions/greetings
```

But, this is not working. Giving the below error:

```
{
    "message": "Function with the requested ID could not be found.",
    "code": 404,
    "type": "function_not_found",
    "version": "1.2.0"
}
```

But, the function is available in the deployments.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://appwrite.io/docs/client/functions?sdk=web-default#functionsCreateExecution), HTTP method should be `POST` and the URL should be `http://localhost/v1/functions/greetings/executions`.

Answer (score 0):

To execute the function, you'll need to make a POST request to `http://localhost/v1/functions/{functionId}/executions`. The folder path is the function name and may not actually be the function ID.

FYI, I recommend using HTTPS instead of HTTP in order to avoid any HTTPS redirect problems.

For reference:

- [Function API docs](https://appwrite.io/docs/client/functions?sdk=web-default#functionsCreateExecution)
- [REST API docs](https://appwrite.io/docs/rest)